# Auto delete a GCE Instance even after I turn off my laptop

Tags: google-compute-engine

I would like to start a job on Compute engine instance, turn off my laptop and have the instance automatically deleted once the remote job is complete (without my laptop running)

Currently I have a script which runs on my laptop which has a delete instance command in the end. But I wish to turn off my laptop, since the remote job can even run for >24hours.

Is it possible to do this? Maybe I can poweroff or delete the instance at the end of the remote job FROM the remote instance itself?

Comment: I think my previous answer to your similar question answers this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608594/how-to-automatically-exit-stop-the-running-instance/16612727#16612727

Comment: Thanks Brian, I see the edits

Comment: Ah gcutil is available from inside and delete instance worked too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is correct you just need to trigger the shutdown command from within your GCE instance when the script has finished and not calling it from your laptop

Comment: Thanks, Brian had indeed answered a related Q in another post, but I was not sure it could be done from within. Now it works!

Comment: what if it has an attached root persistent disk, haven't found a way to delete both the instance and the disk from within the instance. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20846556/delete-gce-instance-and-its-root-persistent-disk-from-within-the-instance