# How to automate the creation of instances?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am trying to automate the creation/launch of instances. I would like Google Compute Engine to launch an instance and execute a certain task for me on a couple of days of the week. Is that possible with GCE somehow?

Answer (score 4):

You can start instances with the Compute Engine API.

Here is an example app which runs an App Engine cron job which deletes instances:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-appengine-timeout-python

You can use that as a starting point, and modify:

- the cron schedule to run on your schedule instead of hourly
- instead of `compute.instances().delete()`, call `compute.instances().insert(INSTANCE)`, where `INSTANCE` is a JSON document which describes the instance you want to create.

(See the [documentation on starting instances](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/instances#start_vm) for details about the JSON doc format, or fill out the form for creating an instance in the [Cloud Console](https://cloud.google.com/console), and then click the "Equivalent REST" link (before creating the instance).

[API documentation for `instances.insert()`](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instances/insert).

In the INSTANCE document, you can add a metadata entry for [Startup Scripts](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/howtos/startupscript). This is a shell script which runs as soon as the instance has booted. You can add the commands to execute your task there.

Once the task is complete, the instance can delete itself. (See this answer for details: [How to automatically exit/stop the running instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608594/how-to-automatically-exit-stop-the-running-instance/16612727#16612727))

Comment: This is the equivalent REST I got: http://pastie.org/private/2sadbbcnjddyhar1rnbm4g. I also modified main.py in the app you posted: http://pastie.org/private/1ukuptdfnycdjsj0g2lb0a. I got stuck at the content of compute.instances().insert(). What exactly do I put in there?