# Terminate google cloud compute engine instance with shell/bash script

Tags: bash, shell, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am using google cloud compute engine for some computational intense tasks (32 parallel processes). My tasks sometimes finished in mid night, and I am wondering is there a way to stop the instance once all my processes stop? I prefer to make a shell script to monitor all my processes and stop the instance when everything is finished.

`halt` or `shutdown` or `poweroff` does not works for me, as my command only submit jobs. The command finished immediately while all processes (computing tasks) kept running on the backend. If I put `halt` or `shutdown` at the end of my command line, the instance simply shut down as I entered the command

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [How to automatically exit/stop the running instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608594/how-to-automatically-exit-stop-the-running-instance).

To summarize, you can simply run `halt` or `shutdown -h now`. Once the operating system halts the instance will terminate and you will no longer be charged.

Alternatively if you've started the instance with the appropriate permissions/scope you could issue the `gcloud compute instances stop` command:

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/stop

Answer (score 1):

I typed:

`gcloud compute instances stop [virtual-machine-instance]`

Therafter, you specify the zone `[zone]` to confirm terminating instance